# How can I make mockito change the content of a method argument?

Tags: java, mockito

Consider the following Java classes

```
public class SomeClass {

 public void validateSomething(List<String> exceptions) {
  //Nothing here
 }
}

public class AnotherClass {

 public SomeClass someClass;

 public void validate() {
 List<String> exceptions = new List<>();
 someClass.validateSomething(exceptions);

 if(exceptions.length > 0) 
  //do something
 }
}
```

How can I use mockito to mock SomeClass and make it add an item to the exceptions list so the code path where exceptions.length > 0 will execute for AnotherClass?

Answer (score 0):

The [`Answer`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html) interface allows your mock to perform any action you desire when a method is called.  In your case, simply take the argument and do with it as you wish.